# Boot a Dell Server with no Monitor

Tags: remote-access

I have a few new dell r210s with windows 2008 server installed on them but I accidentally brought a DVI cable instead of a vga cable for the monitor. Is there anyway to remote into them without a DRAC installed?

(RDC is not setup on them yet because they are out-of-the-box new)

Comment: Do they have serial ports?

Comment: Yes they have serial ports, usb ports, esata, and ethernet

Comment: It's Sunday. If you don't have a box of VGA cables on a shelf in some closet, just walk out of the server room, find a workstation that no one is using at the moment, and borrow the VGA cable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up running down the street to purchase a cable

Answer (score 0):

You could use a serial connection or you could setup an automated install of Windows server and hope it'll boot from the CD(or PXE). Other than that not really with some form of visual interface.